# kableExtra : How can i set to bold the biggest value of the row?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

Suppose i have a table that looks like :

```
x = matrix(runif(10*5),nrow=10,ncol=5)
```

When i display the matrix using `kableextra`, i want **the highest value, per row, of say the last 2 rows, to be bolded.**

I looked at this document https://rdrr.io/cran/kableExtra/f/inst/doc/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf a lot and i did not found how to use cell_spec correctly to perform this goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought this would be easier than it turned out to be.  As far as I can see, this is how to do it:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:  pdf_document
---

```{r}
set.seed(123)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
x <- matrix(round(runif(10*5),2), nrow=10,ncol=5)
j1 <- which.max(x[9,])
j2 <- which.max(x[10,])
col <- seq_len(ncol(x))
x[9,] <- x[9,] %>% cell_spec(bold = col == j1)
x[10,] <- x[10,] %>% cell_spec(bold = col == j2)
x %>% kable(booktabs = TRUE, escape = FALSE)
```
````

A few notes:

- I rounded the values so they aren't so ugly when printed.
- I couldn't see a way to do everything in one pipeline, though there probably is one.  The trouble is that `cell_spec` is designed to work on vectors, not matrices.
- Finally, the `escape = FALSE` in `kable()` is essential:  otherwise you'll see the code to make it bold, rather than the bold entry itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpfull; I had issues with the interface :)