# Especific cells color with Kable in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I have this data frame

[image]

How I can make something like this 
[image]

With Kable package ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kableExtra : How can i set to bold the biggest value of the row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61391380/kableextra-how-can-i-set-to-bold-the-biggest-value-of-the-row)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cell_spec() function in the kableExtra library as well as mutate() in the Dplyr package.

It would look something like this:

```
table <- df %>%  
  mutate(Column = cell_spec(Column, "html", background_as_tile = T, background = factor(Column, colours))) %>%
  kable()...
```

Answer (score 0):

First the dataframe is defined.

```
df = data.frame(c1 = c("0-4","5-14","15-24","25-34"),c2 = c(413,48,155,175),
                    c3 = c(428,33,125,180),c4 = c(345,44,397,642))
```

Here the command for the simple table, without color.

```
df |> knitr::kable(format = "html",escape = FALSE, align = 'c',col.names = c("Grupo","1990","2000","2010"))
```

Now, using the kableExtra package, we can edit the table.

```
library(kableExtra)
df[1,2] = cell_spec(df[1,2], background = "forestgreen",format = "html")  
df[3,3] = cell_spec(df[3,3], background = "orange",format = "html")  

df |> knitr::kable(format = "html",escape = FALSE, align = 'c',col.names = c("Grupo","1990","2000","2010"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).